# How to apply multiple operations on multiple columns based on a single column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe that looks like this:

```
     primaryName    averageRating                 primaryProfession    knownForTitles runtimeMinutes
1   Fred Astaire            7.0      soundtrack,actor,miscellaneous      tt0072308            165
2   Fred Astaire            6.9      soundtrack,actor,miscellaneous      tt0031983             93
3   Fred Astaire            7.0      soundtrack,actor,miscellaneous      tt0050419            103
4   Fred Astaire            7.1      soundtrack,actor,miscellaneous      tt0053137            134
```

So basically i want to take the average of **`averageRating`** column, extract "actor/actress" from **`primaryProfession`** column, count of **`knownForTitles`** column and sum of **`runtimeMinutes`** column based on **`primaryName`** column.
The output dataframe should look like this:

```
     primaryName    averageRating      primaryProfession    knownForTitles   runtimeMinutes
1   Fred Astaire            28                    actor            4            495
```

Any ideas how i can achieve this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df['primaryProfession'].str.contains('actor'), 'primaryProfession'] = 'actor'
df.loc[df['primaryProfession'].str.contains('actress'), 'primaryProfession'] = 'actress'

df.groupby(['primaryName', 'primaryProfession'], as_index=False).agg({'averageRating':'mean', 'knownForTitles':'count', 'runtimeMinutes':'sum'})
```

Comment: It worked for all the columns except the primaryProfession column.

Comment: You mean you just want the name 'actor' but not 'soundtrack,actor,miscellaneous'?

Comment: Exactly! if it contains actor/actress then replace whole string with actor/actress,

Comment: @astroluv check the edited answer

Comment: primaryProfession cannot be aggregated like the others. 
What you can do is to extract the word 'actor'/'actress' for all the records and then you group by name and profession.